# Is there any meaning to the object $\partial_{\mu} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \nu\sigma} + \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\lambda} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\ \nu\sigma}$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

In a calculation I am encountering the object
$$
O^{\rho}_{\ \mu\nu\sigma} \ := \ \partial_{\mu} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \nu\sigma} + \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\lambda}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\ \nu\sigma} \ , 
\tag{1}$$
to be specific I find it contracted with three vectors $V^{\mu}$ as
$$
O^{\rho}_{\ \mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu} V^{\nu} V^{\sigma} \ = \ \left( \partial_{\mu} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \nu\sigma} + \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\lambda}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\ \nu\sigma} \right) V^{\mu} V^{\nu} V^{\sigma} \ . 
\tag{2}$$

I don't think this object is a tensor, but it is reminiciant of the Riemann tensor $$R^{\rho}_{\mu\nu\sigma} = \partial_{\mu} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \nu\sigma} + \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\lambda}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\ \nu\sigma} - \partial_{\nu} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \mu\sigma} + \Gamma^{\rho}_{\ \nu\lambda}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\ \mu\sigma}\tag{3}$$ (it's kind of like $O^{\rho}_{\mu\nu\sigma}$ is "half" of the Riemann tensor).

This has me wondering, is there any meaning that can be attached to $O^{\rho}_{\mu\nu\sigma}$?

Comment: It's pretty close to being the November tensor! https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1904/1904.02008.pdf